# Jest pattern "" - 0 matches (moving from jest 19 -> jest 20)

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I'm using the following jest.unittest.json file (used via jest --config option):

```
{
  "bail": false,
  "verbose": true,
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "typescript-babel-jest"
  },
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/lib",
    "<rootDir>/lib_es6",
    "/node_modules/",
    "fixtures.ts",
    "/fixtures/"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "node"
  ],
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src/__unittests__/Logger",
    "<rootDir>/src/__unittests__/Renderer/renderer.test.ts"
  ],
  "testRegex": "<rootDir>/src/__unittests__/.*\\.test.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$"
}
```

Note the test files are src/**unittests**/Renderer/renderer.test.ts, and so on.

It used to work until jest v19, but after upgrading to v20, this config no longer works.

When I do jest --config jest.unittest.json --verbose, I get:

`Pattern: "" - 0 matches`

Is there anything wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `testRegex` to something like that:

`"(/src/__unittests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's interesting, that you configure 2 `roots` and use only one path in your `testRegex`. Also in the documentation they catch the path and the file name without extension, which is not the way you do it. Catch the path and filename with the parenthesis. See the documentation there (I'd skip `<rootDir>` too as you probably want to use both roots): https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring